# Are database records with sequential primary autoincrement keys likely to be on the same page in an INNODB table?

Tags: mysql, io, primary-key, innodb

Given a table with large auto-incremented integer primary keys, I would like to know if transactions on multiple rows with consecutive or near consecutive primary keys are likely to result in fewer disk IO operations than the same transactions on the same number of rows with values that are more widely distributed.

So for example:

How would a `SELECT WHERE id IN` statement on records with the primary keys:
10202, 10203, 10205, 10207, 10208, 10209, compare to the same statement with the keys: 7, 10202, 52401, 28772, 924, 1189, assuming all the records are considerably smaller than 1/6th of the page size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gordan pointed out the records are stored ordered by the primary key. It doesn't matter in what order they're inserted though.

I'd say InnoDB is likely to make less IO requests if the primary key values are clustered. Let me explain why.

Let's say all InnoDB pages are on disk, there is nothing in the buffer pool. To pull record 10202 InnoDB will need to read the root page, all non-leaf pages along the way to the leaf page. All pages it read will be stored in the buffer pool.

Next read - 10203. Most likely InnoDB won't do any disk read because all pages are already in the buffer pool (unless a less likely case when 10203 is on a neighboring leaf page).

Now, if InnoDB needs to read some id from other part of the index, it will need to read the root page (most likely cached), non-leaf pages (some of them are most likely cached. Take into account B+tree is quite shallow), and the leaf page (not cached). So, you get an extra disk read.

Comment: I think you are conflating logical and physical sequentiality.

Comment: I understand the records on a given page are not stored in sorted order, but as a group they are in fact sequential. Cf. https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/btree-index-structures-in-innodb/

Comment: @BillKarwin, records inside a page are sorted by PK.

Comment: Okay I haven't examined it myself, I'm just reading jcole's description. He says they are in a linked list by PK order, but they may not be physically in PK order within a page.

Comment: Ah, within a page. Yes, that's correct. The list logically is ordered by the PK. Physically, inside the page, the order may be different. In fact, the supremum record always comes second. From what I've seen the records are mostly sorted even physically. I guess it's because during a page split InnoDB reorganizes the page completely. But I've seen pages with individual records show up in random places. Maybe due to a PK update before the page split?. Anyway, that doesn't matter for in context of disk activity, InnoDB reads data in whole pages.

Comment: It does not matter how the records _within_ a page are ordered.  That has no impact on I/O and whether nearby ids are likely to be in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are, if they were inserted in that order. In reality, however, overall database I/O pattern is pretty random, so the net benefit may be difficult to measure conclusively.

Comment: Yes, they are no matter in what order the records are inserted. InnoDB sorts records by the primary key to store them in a page.

Comment: @akuzminsky logically sequential, not physically sequential. If you insert a record with a PK out of order, a new page is allocated that cannot be physically sequential on disk.

Comment: neighboring leaf pages can be in different parts of a disk. records inside *one* page ordered by PK. makes sense now?